# Xcode Tab Bar Application

Tags: xcode

I want to ask Some questions about tabbar bar application in xcode.

1) When I Change a the tab by taping it , how to i detect the change ?
2) view did load only runs once .. how do i make it run every time i come to that tab?
3) if i run a timer on first tab and move to the second tab will it continue to run?
4) how to change the tagvalue of the second tab when in first tab ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Did you try reading the docs?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> As the user interacts with a tab bar interface, the tab bar controller
>   object sends notifications about the interactions to its delegate

(2) If you need `viewDidLoad` to run multiple times, you don't understand what `viewDidLoad` is for. Use the framework by letting it use you. You get events when you get them; your job is to know what they are and what they signify. Don't misuse `viewDidLoad`; decide what you need to do, and find the event that fits that need.

(3) Sure, why wouldn't it?

(4) I don't know what a "tagvalue" is. Can you express the question using accurate terminology?

Comment: 1). I did but couldn't find exact answers 2) if I don't use viewdidload then what should I use 3) that's now cleared ty 4) tagvalue is small red circle for notification